# Playing (and having issues) with Layout on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am having some problems getting the result I want using `RelativeLayout`, also wondering if I should also use `LinearLayout` at the same time. Here is my code:

```
package me.soft.myapp

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.TypedValue
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.View
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.RelativeLayout
import android.widget.ScrollView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit private var constraintLayout: ConstraintLayout

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        constraintLayout = this.findViewById(R.id.activity_main)

        val relatLayOut = RelativeLayout(this)
        relatLayOut.id = View.generateViewId()
        val rllyLOP = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
        relatLayOut.layoutParams = rllyLOP
        constraintLayout.addView(relatLayOut)

        // We define 2 colored stripes and one scroll view.
        val bannerOne = stripe("Hello wonderful world of yours ...",
            Color.rgb(0xEE,0xEE,0x22))
        val bannerTwo = stripe("The purpose of our lives is to be happy.",
            Color.rgb(0x22,0xEE,0xEE))
        val scrolZone = scrollBlock(longNumberString(1000))

        // We add them to the global layout.
        relatLayOut.addView(bannerOne)
        relatLayOut.addView(bannerTwo)
        relatLayOut.addView(scrolZone)

        // Set the layout and order of the components:
        val layoutOption = 2//1

        if (layoutOption == 1) {
            setViewBelow(bannerTwo,bannerOne)
            setViewBelow(scrolZone,bannerTwo)
        }

        if (layoutOption == 2) {
            setViewBelow(scrolZone, bannerOne)
            setViewBelow(bannerTwo, scrolZone)
        }
    }


    fun Int.dpToPixels(context: Context):Float = TypedValue.applyDimension(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,this.toFloat(),context.resources.displayMetrics
    )


    fun stripe(display:String, bgc: Int): RelativeLayout {
        val lnlyLOP = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        val lnlyOut = RelativeLayout(this)
        lnlyOut.id = View.generateViewId()
        lnlyOut.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        lnlyOut.layoutParams = lnlyLOP
        lnlyOut.setBackgroundColor(bgc)

        val theLabel = TextView(this)
        theLabel.text = display
        theLabel.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 25.dpToPixels(this))
        theLabel.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        lnlyOut.addView(theLabel)
        return lnlyOut
    } /* End of stripe */


    fun scrollBlock(display:String): ScrollView {
        val scrolViw = ScrollView(this)
        scrolViw.id = View.generateViewId()
        val rllyLOP = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
        scrolViw.layoutParams = rllyLOP

        val theLabel = TextView(this)
        theLabel.text = display
        scrolViw.addView(theLabel)

        return scrolViw
    } /* End of scrollBlock */


    fun setViewBelow(theView: View, referView: View) { // To set theView below referView.
        val memoLOP = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        memoLOP.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, referView.id)
        theView.layoutParams = memoLOP
    } /* End of setViewBelow */


    fun longNumberString(n:Int): String { // To make a long string of numbers.
        if (n<0) return ""
        var resultStr = "0"
        for (i in 1..n) {resultStr += "-$i"}
        return resultStr
    } /* End of longNumberString */
}
```

This code is working as I expect when I use *layoutOption = 1*.
But not when I use *layoutOption = 2*.

Here what I get on the device for *layoutOption = 1* :

[image]

Here what I get on the device for *layoutOption = 2* :

[image]

But here what I expect for *layoutOption = 2* :

[image]

Obviously I am doing something wrong for the result I want with *layoutOption = 2*.

Can anyone see where the mistake is?

Here is the XML file, just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/   res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

Comment: You should be using layouts how they are required like if you want to place something in linear manner then you should use linear layout which can be horizontal or vertical. While if your view/controls needs to be placed relative to each other then you should use relative layout.

Comment: Yes I know that. But the tricky part for me here is the presence of a ScrollView. As shown is the third image I want it to occupy the space between the two stripes. The three elements should be aligned vertically indeed, but when I tried using LinearLayout to solve my problem it did not work. This is why I thought RelativeLayout would allow me to force the scroll view to be above the last stripe. Like now why is bannerTwo disappearing with layoutOption=2 ?

Comment: So top and bottom strips will be fixed and middle portion should scroll, is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how you write!

Comment: Please upload your code over here and i will provide you solution

Comment: You have all the code already.

Comment: I need XML file's code

Comment: OK, I just added it. But I would like to solve this issue in code. (i.e. in Kotlin)

Comment: That is just root tag, I would need full code as lot of changes will be done.

Comment: There no other XML since I create every component in the Kotlin code as you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using RelativeLayout, you could do something like this to achieve your desired results:

a. Make your bannerTwo bottom align to Parent bottom using [LayoutParams#alignParentBottom](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams#attr_android:layout_alignParentBottom)

b. Make your ScrollView Bottom to be Top of bannerTwo using [LayoutParams#layout_above](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams#attr_android:layout_above)

c. Similarly Make your ScrollView Top to be Bottom of bannerOne using [LayoutParams#layout_below](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams#attr_android:layout_below)

This will lock in the size of the ScrollView between the two banners while making the bannerOne and bannerTwo visible on screen. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Pratik_K. Though I accepted your answer, I also added mine, because there is quite a bit of work between you (XML type) hints and the dynamic version of the solution I was hoping for. I mean I wanted to solve the issue in the kotlin code, if possible without touching any XML (which I did). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the tips provided in **Pratik K**'s answer; here is how I finally solved the problem from the code in the post. I replaced the following lines of code:

```
    if (layoutOption == 2) {
        setViewBelow(scrolZone, bannerOne)
        setViewBelow(bannerTwo, scrolZone)
    }
```

by the ones below:

```
    if (layoutOtion == 2) {
        stickViewAtBottom(bannerTwo)
        setViewBetween(scrolZone,bannerOne,bannerTwo)
     }
```

Where the two new functions *stickViewAtBottom()* and *setViewBetween()* are defined as:

```
fun stickViewAtBottom(theView: View) { // To set theView at the bottom of its parent.
    val memoLOP = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    val parentID = (theView.parent as View).id
    memoLOP.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, parentID)
    theView.layoutParams = memoLOP
} /* End of stickViewAtBottom */


fun setViewBetween(theView: View, aboveView: View, beneathView: View) {
    val memoLOP = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    memoLOP.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, aboveView.id)
    memoLOP.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, beneathView.id)
    theView.layoutParams = memoLOP
} /* End of setViewBetween */
```